# ¿AOS Library no funciona al hacer scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, librería

Muy buenas a todos.
Recientemente he encontrado una librería de animación en el scroll de una página llamado **AOS - Animate on Scroll Library**. (http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

El caso es que estoy intentando implementarlo a mi página HTML y me pasa lo siguiente; solo funciona al hacer zoom en la página, no al hacer el scroll. 
Y he descubierto que es porque tengo definido en el css

```
html, body {
 overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

Si esta parte del código no está definida, me pasa esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toda la parte derecha de la página se hace enorme aunque le haya dicho en el html esto:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Cuál sería la solución para que el código de AOS me funcionara con el overflow de x en hidden? Es una parte importante del CSS ya que si no la defino el width de la página se hace más grande de lo que el dispositivo que la muestra en realidad es.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Se ha solucionado el problema cambiando el código original por:

```
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

añadiéndolo solo en el body y no tener ningún problema con el scroll horizontal.